# Zhong Shan Suit Inner Shirt Cantonese Name

Tags: cantonese

I would like to ask the Cantonese speakers about the 中山裝.

As we know, 中山裝 is similar to the western suit, 西裝, it is designed with the jacket (外套) and the inner shirt (長袖衫). However, my friends told me that the "長袖衫" is called 底 (pronounced as 桶底 tung2 dai2) in Cantonese.

So, is it correct?

[image: 中山裝]

Answer (score 1):

[CantoDict](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/) doesn't contain a word like「底」, and given that the character「」is located in the CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B block, it's not a common use character. An appropriate reading and meaning for「」appears in the Kangxi Dictionary:

[image]

However, that definition says「衣短袖」, which is almost the exact opposite to「長袖衫」. If whoever you heard it from is not mistaken, then that will be a [Cantonese dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yue_Chinese#Distribution_and_variation) word, and not [Standard Cantonese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantonese).

The closest entry in CantoDict which matches the meaning is「底衫」(*dai2 saam1*, ***undershirt***). I'm going to note here that「長袖衫」doesn't actually mean *inner shirt*, it means *long-sleeved shirt*, and if this tailor that you're seeing designs inner shirts with short sleeves instead then「底」(or maybe「底衫」) sounds entirely appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

The name Zhong Shan comes from the name of Dr. Sun Yat-sen, but this jacket is also known as Lenin suit (Lenin being the leader of the former USSR) or Indian suit (a little different though), so the inner shirt is no more than the shirt westerners wear for a suit. It is not the original product of Guangdong Province of China.

Comment: I knew it has been modified with the western suit, but we do also have a special Cantonese name for each part of the Zhong Shan Suit.
I knew its history, but I am asking for the name of the inner shirt. We neither call it long sleeve shirt nor 長袖衫。 We have a special name for it.

Comment: Since it is not the original of Cantonese people, actually the local people do not have the unified name for this thing. That is what I wanted to tell you. it is something like the name of a NBA star, since it is translated from English, so Hong Kong, Taiwan and mainland China and Chinese living elsewhere have different version of such name in Chinese. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Ya I knew. That's why I am asking the name in Cantonese. :)

Comment: I live in the Cantonese region of China and  myself can speak good Cantonese, I am not aware that there is such a thing.  Some Chinese people may have told you that name, but it doesn't sound so convincing, because not so many people know it or it is obsolete.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your information. But I'm sure that the old tailor in Cantonese region know this name.

Answer (score -1):

I know you are asking for Cantonese, but perhaps this word in Mandarin may lead you (or another Cantonese speaker) to the actual term:

衬衫 chen4shan1

This is a generic term for single-layer shirts, including undershirts.